# ListenAndServerTLS keeps failing with error: failed to find any PEM data in certificate input

Tags: ssl, go, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I bought an SSL certificate from Godaddy for a web site.
I added the files in the server and run the service and it just returns an error:

> failed to find any PEM data in certificate input

I used cat to generate a server.pem file with all the files, even added a godaddy pem intermediate pem file they provide for a G2 Certificate Chain and nothing.

```bsh
cat generated-private-key.txt > server.pem
cat 678f65b8a7391017.crt >> server.pem
cat gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt >> server.pem
cat gdig2.crt.pem >> server.pem
```

Using self signed certificate works but off course it's not usable in real world.

Code attempt 1:

```golang
log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServeTLS(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", configuration.HttpServer.Address, configuration.HttpServer.Port), "server.pem", "generated-private-key.txt", router))
```

Code attempt 2:

```golang
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair("server.pem","generated-private-key.txt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
    }
    pem, err := ioutil.ReadFile("gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to read client certificate authority: %v", err)
    }
    certpool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if !certpool.AppendCertsFromPEM(pem) {
        log.Fatalf("Can't parse client certificate authority")
    }
    tlsConfig := &tls.Config{
        ClientCAs:    certpool,
        Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }

    srv := &http.Server{
        Addr: fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", configuration.HttpServer.Address, configuration.HttpServer.Port),
        Handler: router,
        ReadTimeout: time.Duration(5) * time.Second,
        WriteTimeout: time.Duration(5) * time.Second,
        TLSConfig: tlsConfig,
    }
    log.Fatal(srv.ListenAndServeTLS("678f65b8a7391017.crt","generated-private-key.txt"))
```

Both give the same error.

I need to have this up and running as I already have the back-end done but now I just want to enable HTTPS for productive environment.

Comment: It looks like you're starting your certificate with the contents of your private key.  Try skipping the first line of your certificate creation script and trying again.

Answer (score 1):

Finally solved it, I had to combine both generated-private-key.txt and generated-csr.txt that Godaddy provided me into a single "server.key" file.
Incredible what lack of knowledge of certain things end up wasting so much time.
But I guess that's why were here, for the thrill of exploring.
Thank you everyone for the help!

Comment: Hey, I am in the same boat. How did your server.key look like? How did you append the content of each file?

Answer (score 0):

I've struggled with this myself and I *think* your issue here is that you need to process the keys before presenting for the `http.Server`, and you'll need to include the RootCA. I've downloaded an SSL from GoDaddy (using the `Other` option) and grabbed their `gd_bundle-g2.crt` RootCA from [here](https://ssl-ccp.godaddy.com/repository). Once you've grabbed that, create a function like below (added a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/sebito91/21d6b6536a3f3add1d8be2738ee1fcae)):

```
func genTLS() (*tls.Config, error) {
    caCert, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/sborza/gd_bundle-g2.crt")
    if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("read root cert: %s", err.Error())
    }

    // **** START PRIV KEY PROCESSING ****

    clientBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/sborza/sborza_dev.key")
    if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("read client priv key: %s", err.Error())
    }

    cb, _ := pem.Decode(clientBytes)
    k, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(cb.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse client privkey: %s", err.Error())
    }

    clientKey, _ := x509.MarshalPKCS8PrivateKey(k)
    clientKeyPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
            Type:  "PRIVATE KEY",
            Bytes: clientKey,
    })

    // **** END PRIV KEY PROCESSING ****
    // **** START CERT PROCESSING ****

    certBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("/home/sborza/sborza_dev.pem")
    if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("read client cert: %s", err.Error())
    }

    cbk, _ := pem.Decode(certBytes)
    certs, err := x509.ParseCertificates(cbk.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("parse client cert: %s", err.Error())
    }

    clientCertPEM := pem.EncodeToMemory(&pem.Block{
            Type:  "CERTIFICATE",
            Bytes: certs[0].Raw,
    })

    // **** END CERT PROCESSING ****
    // **** START TLS CONFIG ****

    cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(clientCertPEM, clientKeyPEM)
    if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("tls key pair: %s", err.Error())
    }
    caCertPool := x509.NewCertPool()
    if ok := caCertPool.AppendCertsFromPEM(caCert); !ok {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("append cert: %s", err.Error())
    }

    return &tls.Config{
            RootCAs:      caCertPool,
            Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
    }, nil
    // **** END TLS CONFIG ****
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per one of the other comments, for the first param to ListenAndServeTLS, the GoDaddy cert and chain files have to be concatenated. Here is an example

```
var srv http.Server
srv.Handler = yourHandler
srv.Addr = ":443"

// Load cert files
chainBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt") // GoDaddy chain
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
certBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("server.crt") // Your server cert
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
keyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile("server.key") // Your server key
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

// Concatenate chain and cert
b := bytes.NewBuffer(certBytes)
b.Write([]byte("\n"))
b.Write(chainBytes)

// Setup TLS
cert, err := tls.X509KeyPair(b.Bytes(), keyBytes)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
cfg := &tls.Config{
    Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert},
}
srv.TLSConfig = cfg

// Start server
err = srv.ListenAndServeTLS("", "")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

My experience was that just using the cert file is fine in latest versions of browsers like **Google Chrome**, but I would get TLS errors with clients like **HTTPie** or **CURL**

```
certificate verify failed
```

And various errors on the server

```
tls: bad record MAC
tls: unknown certificate authority
```

Concatenating the cert and chain files solved above errors.

Answer (score -1):

The issue was with the key file. This was the same key I used given by GoDaddy without any modification. The beginning of the file had some issue (like UTF-8 BOM at the start of the file or similar) as @SteffenUllrich  mentioned. To fix this, I added an empty line just above the key file and it worked.

Finally, the key looks like:

```
<Empty line>
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
wlWPpSnGEdNjRapfW/6+xzjDVAaKC41c5b07OAviFchwqGI+88
aZGwBJnTgkbsLddddddd=
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: While this might solve this problem in the specific case it is very likely only a side effect of opening the file in some editor and writing it again and thereby implicitly cleaning up some problems of the key file which should not have been there in the first place (like UTF-8 BOM at the start of the file or similar). The certificate information are definitely not needed. Likely just adding an empty line at the beginning of the file would have done this too, since this way any UTF-8 BOM would not be longer directly at the beginning of the PEM data.

Comment: I am still working on it. I will update this answer after little more debugging and conclusions. Thanks you for helping me out @SteffenUllrich